# NURBS/B-Spline Visualization with geomdl 3D not working (shows empty image)

Tags: python, spline, nurbs

I need to create NURBS surfaces for a project. For that i want to use the geomdl package. I installed it via conda and i tried it with the examples given [here](https://nurbs-python.readthedocs.io/en/5.x/visualization.html). It works with the 2d examples but not with the 3d examples.
This is a Code for a B-Spline Curve:

```
from geomdl import BSpline
from geomdl import utilities
from geomdl.visualization import VisMPL

ctrlpts = [[5.0, 5.0, 0.0], [5.0, 10.0, 0.0], [10.0, 10.0, 5.0], [10.0, 5.0, 5.0], [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], [5.0, 10.0, 10.0], [10.0, 10.0, 10.0], [10.0, 5.0, 10.0], [5.0, 5.0, 15.0], [5.0, 10.0, 15.0], [10.0, 10.0, 15.0], [10.0, 5.0, 20.0], [5.0, 5.0, 20.0]]

# Create a B-Spline curve instance
curve = BSpline.Curve()

# Set up curve
curve.degree = 3
curve.ctrlpts = ctrlpts

# Auto-generate knot vector
curve.knotvector = utilities.generate_knot_vector(curve.degree, curve.ctrlpts_size)

# Set evaluation delta
curve.delta = 0.01

# Plot the control point polygon and the evaluated curve
curve.vis = VisMPL.VisCurve3D()
curve.render()
```

[The visual outcome looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge6d4.png)
No axes, no coordinates even if i tell the curve.render function to show them.
I also tried to delete geomdl and reinstall it. Without success.

[It should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3yNm.png)

Comment: i have the same issue. did you ever get this resolved ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I installed the package at my work PC where it works just fine. Do you use Windows 11? That is the only real reason i could come up with (besides an error while downloading). Let me know if you find a solution!

Comment: No i am using linux. Debian distro. I insallted VTK and started using VisVTK instead of VisMPL and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just use VisVTK module instead of VisMPL; it will work fine.No need to install it separately; it is part of the "geomdl" package.

Here is the modified code:

```
from geomdl import BSpline
from geomdl import utilities
from geomdl.visualization import VisVTK

ctrlpts = [[5.0, 5.0, 0.0], [5.0, 10.0, 0.0], [10.0, 10.0, 5.0], [10.0, 
5.0, 5.0], [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], [5.0, 10.0, 10.0], [10.0, 10.0, 10.0], [10.0, 
5.0, 10.0], [5.0, 5.0, 15.0], [5.0, 10.0, 15.0], [10.0, 10.0, 15.0], [10.0, 
5.0, 20.0], [5.0, 5.0, 20.0]]

# Create a B-Spline curve instance
curve = BSpline.Curve()

# Set up curve
curve.degree = 3
curve.ctrlpts = ctrlpts

# Auto-generate knot vector
curve.knotvector = utilities.generate_knot_vector(curve.degree, 
curve.ctrlpts_size)

# Set evaluation delta
curve.delta = 0.01

# Plot the control point polygon and the evaluated curve
curve.vis = VisVTK.VisCurve3D()
curve.render()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it for me for surface plotting be replacing line 430 of VisMPL.py

```
# Start plotting of the surface and the control points grid
fig = plt.figure(figsize=self.vconf.figure_size, dpi=self.vconf.figure_dpi)
ax = Axes3D(fig)
```

with:

```
# Start plotting of the surface and the control points grid
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
```

I didn't check the hole code, maybe you need to replace it somewhere else too. Note that the settings now do not work anymore. But this can surely be fixed.